# Why can't i run rake -f?

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

I really have no idea what im doing. I'm trying to get rake to work so I can run `rake workers:start` but without having to have the working directory be the same as the folder of the rake file.

for example if i'm in my app directory, the above command works fine, but if i run `rake -f ~/Code/my-app/Rakefile workers:start` it says "Cannot load such file -- ./database

I'm using Sinatra (rack), and ultimately my goal is to try and install god so I can create a resque worker in production

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/main"
require 'resque/tasks'

namespace :workers do

  desc "Launch single worker for processing jobs"
  task :start do
    ENV['QUEUE']   ||= '*'
    puts "=== Launching single worker on '#{ENV['QUEUE']}' queue(s) with PID #{Process.pid}"
    Rake::Task['resque:work'].invoke
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rake -f ~/Code/my-app/Rakefile rake:workers:start
                                ^ shouldn't need this one.
```

Also you might want to `cd` to appropriate dir before running `rake`.

```
cd ~/Code/my-app && rake workers:start
```

Comment: oops... the second rake command wasnt in there when i run. That was an accident. Still doesnt work. The only reason i asked instead of using the cd command was so I can get it to work with God. I know god requires the command you need to run it. i try running it manually in terminal from any location and it still doesnt work

Comment: Here's my [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) script for god, if it helps: https://gist.github.com/1549719

Comment: Here's my `master.god` config file: https://gist.github.com/1549724 And the rest of config files look very similar to [this one](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/blob/master/examples/god/resque.god)